# How to get range from excel binary data stored in db

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, excel

I have excel binary data in saved in sql server 2005, now i need to get selected range ex("A" to "O")
from the binary data, how to achieve this in c#

Comment: @stacknewbee: if you stored files in filesystem then you wouldn't experienced such issue.

Comment: The excel data is stored as varbinary in SQL, now i want retrive back the excel but only some selected range("A" to "o"). Is it possible???

Comment: No it isn't possible in a simple manner. You'll have to read the __entire__ Excel file from the database, then parse it to extract the range that you want

Comment: Currently i'm doing like that only, but wanted to know wether it is possible r not.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to save he binary data to a file, then use "Visual Studio Tools for Office" to open the file from your program and use the methods from the excel object model to acces the data in the cells.